# how can I block a specific folder from viewing it's content to guests?

Tags: php, mysql, html, permissions, file-permissions

I have a website with a simple login and only a very limited amount of users that I set myself.

My logged in users has more site content shown to them while the guests has a limited content shown.
This is achieved through the `if($logged_in)`

My problem is that it is possible for a guest user to just navigate his browser to the "hidden" content. How can I set permissions for a folder to allow only my logged in users to view it and block the content for guests?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In which context are you : PHP (generate HTML), Apache (directory listing) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make an index file (inside of the "hidden" folder) that displays the information to the users rather than it just be open to exploration, then you can easily control who can see what. It's not too hard and gives you a lot more control.